# iterator skip_while that does not turn off

Tags: rust, iterator

***tl;dr*** rust iterator method `skip_while` stops skipping elements (always returns elements) after the first failed test. How to continue skipping (i.e. do not "turn off" skipping)?

Rust iterator method [`skip_while()` documentation reads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip_while)

> `skip_while()` takes a closure as an argument. It will call this closure on each element of the iterator, and ignore elements until it returns `false`.
>
> After `false` is returned, `skip_while()`’s job is over, and the rest of the elements are yielded.

I want `skip_while`'s "job to not be over" after seeing a `false`.  What is a Rustic way to use iterators to accomplish this?

So for example, [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=070105b8dc0583434e5860b5a1b15ac6)

```rust
fn main() {
    let lines = [
        "",
        "a",
        "",
        "b",
        "",
        "c",
    ];
    for line in lines.iter().skip_while(|x| x.is_empty()) {
        println!("line is {:?}, {:?}", line, line.is_empty());
    }
}
```

prints

```text
line is "a", false
line is "", true
line is "b", false
line is "", true
line is "c", false
```

I would like code that prints

```text
line is "a", false
line is "b", false
line is "c", false
```

How to do this using iterators and iterator filters?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`filter` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter).

[Code snippet](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b50afa74bfb6f2c84ceefb965532007e)

```rust
fn main() {
    let lines = [
        "",
        "a",
        "",
        "b",
        "",
        "c",
    ];
    for line in lines.iter().filter(|x| !x.is_empty()) {
        println!("line is {:?}, {:?}", line, line.is_empty());
    }
}
```

prints

```text
line is "a", false
line is "b", false
line is "c", false
```